# How do I check the Currently Visible Activity and fire one of its Methods from Anywhere?

Tags: android, android-c2dm

My app has a chat screen to send and receive messages. Whenever a message is received a push notification comes in and shows the latest received message. This all works fine.

But when I get my push notification I would like the chat screen to refresh itself. I guess this would require knowing if the chat screen is currently visible or not. How can I do this from the `onReceive()` method of my `BroadcastReceiver`?

Here's a little pseudo code (in my `BroadcastReceiver` subclass):

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    if(currentlyVisibleActivity.getClass() == chatScreenActivity.class())
    {
        ((chatScreenActivity)currentlyVisibleActivity).getMessages();
    }

}
```

I would like to know how to get the currentlyVisibleActvity and make it `call getMessages()` if it's a chatScreenActivity.

Comment: Are you storing the chat messages in a ContentProvider or similar?

Comment: When testing out the chat feature I pinged the server every 15 seconds to get new messages, then stored them on a local SQLite database. This was only for testing of the getMessages() method, I know that pinging the server every 15 seconds is not a good thing. So I'm looking to call getMessages() whenever I receive a push notification.

Comment: Right-o. So implement a proper ContentProvider (check out [SQLiteContentProvider](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.3_r1/com/android/apps/tag/provider/SQLiteContentProvider.java/?v=source) for a proper abstract implementation to extend). Whenever you call #getMessages() or similar just trigger the [notifyChange()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#notifyChange%28android.net.Uri,%20android.database.ContentObserver%29) method and any ListView (or similar) that is properly implemented will update.

Comment: I'm sorry I may have not worded the question properly (please see edits above). The getMessages() method works fine, I just want to know how to call it from the BroadcastReceiver's onReceive() method. I want to know how to check to see if the chat screen activity is visible or not.

Comment: You typically *don't* do stuff like that in a receiver - you dispatch the work to an IntentService or similar that does the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are planning the following setup?

```
C2DM -> YourBroadcastReceiver -> somehow call #getMessages()
```

How about having the following components:

```
A BroadcastReceiver <for receiving C2DM push notifications>
An IntentService <for executing #getMessages()>
A ContentProvider <for storing the results of #getMessages()>
An Activity <for displaying the contents of ContentProvider>
```

1. Basically, C2DM triggers your receiver which calls `#startService`, triggering
   your `IntentService`.
2. Your `IntentService` calls `#getMessages()` and stores the messages in your
   `ContentProvider`.
3. Whenever a change is performed on the data in the `ContentProvider` you will
   trigger `ContentResolver#notifyChange()`.
4. If your `Activity` is showing and uses, for instance, a `CursorAdapter` to read
   from the `ContentProvider` it will automatically refresh.

Sending a chat message would also store a row in the `ContentProvider` in this scenario - automatically updating the UI just as a received message.